# clipnorm vs clipvalue vs global_clipnorm in tf.keras.optimizers.Adam

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am looking at the definition of `clipvalue, clipnorm, global_clipnorm` arguments in `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam). I have some questions related to that. The description of the arguments mentions following:

- `clipnorm`:   Float. If set, the gradient of each weight is individually clipped so that its norm is no higher than this value.
- `clipvalue`:  Float. If set, the gradient of each weight is clipped to be no higher than this value.
- `global_clipnorm`:    Float. If set, the gradient of all weights is clipped so that their global norm is no higher than this value.

Questions:

- As gradient of a weight (as the description says each weight) is 1-dimensional, clipnorm and clipvalue should be the same. Are there some scenarios in which clipnorm and clipvalue are different?
- Seems global_clipnorm computes norm over all the weights in the model. From the available options, it seems we don’t have any argument in tf.keras.optimizers.Adam to do that clipnorm over the weights of a layer. Do we have that option with the api?

Answer (score 0):

well, you are right if we have a 1-dimensional gradient then the `clip_norm` and `clip_value` do the same job. But if we go deep inside then `clip_norm` controls the **rate** or **speed** at which the gradient is flowing across different dimensions, and the other foremost factor is the **magnitude** of a gradient in different dimensions. There `clip_norm` will only **clip** the values between two bounds when it reaches the threshold while `gradient flowing in a different direction may vary in magnitude`. So, here `clip_norm` can act as a regularizer; As the magnitude of the gradient is large in some directions and small in other dimensions may affect the learning. So, here `clip_norm` can act as a regularizer so it will clip the magnitude of the gradient which are causing the **zip zag** effect during training.

For your other question during training when you are training the `Model` you can use `clip_norm` or `clip_value` functions before passing it to `optimizer.update()` function in tensorflow. This is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the documentation is confusing : we can think that clipnorm and clipvalue are the same or even clipnorm and global_clipnorm are the same.
The internal implementation of The clipnorm in the "optimizer" uses this methods:

```
grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list)
```

and

```
for g in grads:
 f.clip_by_norm(g,clipnorm)
```

[https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.12.0/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py#L275](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.12.0/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py#L885)

lets take an example using the same methods:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='relu',kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=1, seed=1)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2 , kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=1, seed=2))
])

x = tf.constant([[1., 2. ,3.,4.]])

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  # Forward pass
  y = model(x)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(y**2)

# Calculate gradients with respect to every trainable variable
grads  = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
print("loop")
for g in grads:
    print(g)
    print(tf.clip_by_norm(g ,1.))
    print("------")


> the output :
> 
> > loop tf.Tensor( [[ 5.4646683  0.        24.63168  ]  [10.929337   0.  
> > 49.26336  ]  [16.394005   0.        73.895035 ]  [21.858673   0.        98.52672  ]], shape=(4, 3), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor( [[0.03954357 0.         0.17824039]  [0.07908715 0.         0.35648078]  [0.11863072 0.         0.53472114]  [0.15817429 0.         0.71296155]], shape=(4, 3), dtype=float32)
> > ------ tf.Tensor([ 5.4646683  0.        24.63168  ], shape=(3,), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor([0.21658908 0.         0.97626287],
> > shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
> > ------ tf.Tensor( [[ -6.7116046 -27.5379   ]  [ -0.         -0.       ]  [-24.11649   -98.95063  ]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(
> > [[-0.06348615 -0.26048544]  [-0.         -0.        ]  [-0.22812176
> > -0.9359899 ]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32)
> > ------ tf.Tensor([ -3.2823584 -13.467608 ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor([-0.23679112 -0.9715606 ], shape=(2,),
> dtype=float32)
> > ------
```

as you can see, the variable grads is a list of weights and biases of each layer and then the clip_by_norm is implemented on each one.

lets use clipvalue :

```
for g in grads:
    print(g)
    print(tf.clip_by_value(g ,clip_value_min=-1, clip_value_max=1))
    print("------")

tf.Tensor(
[[ 5.4646683  0.        24.63168  ]
 [10.929337   0.        49.26336  ]
 [16.394005   0.        73.895035 ]
 [21.858673   0.        98.52672  ]], shape=(4, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1.]], shape=(4, 3), dtype=float32)
------
tf.Tensor([ 5.4646683  0.        24.63168  ], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1. 0. 1.], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
------
tf.Tensor(
[[ -6.7116046 -27.5379   ]
 [ -0.         -0.       ]
 [-24.11649   -98.95063  ]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[-1. -1.]
 [-0. -0.]
 [-1. -1.]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32)
------
tf.Tensor([ -3.2823584 -13.467608 ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([-1. -1.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
------
```

While clipnorm is implemented on the weight of each layer, global_clipnorm is implemented on the weight of all layers of the model.
for your last question

> Seems global_clipnorm computes norm over all the weights in the model.
> From the available options, it seems we don’t have any argument in
> tf.keras.optimizers.Adam to do that clipnorm over the weights of a
> layer.

you can see that the clipnorm is already done on each layer